# VBA regex to remove all but the email addresses

Tags: regex, vba

I am trying to clean up a string of email addresses:

> bruce.wayne@batcave.com;#30;#clarke.kent@dailyplanet.com;#32;#the.joker@arkhamassylum.com;#33

I don't know how many emails will be in the list and the numbers will change length too.

I have tried:

```
(?!([\w-]+\.)[\w-]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w;]+)
```

as a pattern but it doesn't work.

This is all being done in VBA.

Comment: I suggest you include the VBA code that applies this pattern.

Comment: so what's the actual problem here?

Comment: so i am using the above regex to try and remove the numbers and hash signs from the string but i am, in fact, removing the email address.  I need to flip it around so the email addresses remain and the numbers and hash signs are removed.

Comment: That explanation of the issue should be inside the question body. Few people read comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "I need to flip it around so the email addresses remain and the
>   numbers and hash signs are removed"

you could target the stuff you want to remove instead of targeting the valid parts:

```
#\d+;?#?
```

"a pound sign, followed by one or more numbers, followed by a semicolon (maybe), followed by a pound sign (maybe)"

now simply do a replace with empty string and [you should have a clean list of email addresses](https://regex101.com/r/wN6mR9/1).

Comment: regex isn't the correct tool to use in this instance. While your solution works, this is actually a variant of "csv" storage. Instead of commas, the letter combination `";#"` is used, which makes splitting the more semantically correct solution :)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a regex to do this.

Your addresses are delimited with a `",#"` string. Use the `Split` function to split your string into an array of values. Then iterate the array and only bother with entries that contain a `@` character.

Below code produces this output:

> ```
> bruce.wayne@batcave.com
> clarke.kent@dailyplanet.com
> the.joker@arkhamassylum.com
> ```

```
Sub Test()
    Const stringValues As String = "bruce.wayne@batcave.com;#30;#clarke.kent@dailyplanet.com;#32;#the.joker@arkhamassylum.com;#33"
    Dim values As Variant
    values = Split(stringValues, ";#")

    Dim value As Variant
    For Each value In values
        If InStr(value, "@") Then
            ' You've got mail!
            Debug.Print value
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your real input strings, you could come up with sth. like:

```
([-.\w]+@[-.\w]+);
```

See [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/hY2nY9/1). "Remove all but" comes down to extracting what you want.

Comment: @rock321987: Bad habit, admittedly.